# Windows 7 x64 refuses to boot due to an SSD-related issue

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, freeze

This is my setup:

- **Motherboard:** ASUS P5KC
- **Hard drive:** Intel SSD 330 series connected via IDE
- **OS:** Windows 7 x64

The thing is that after having installed the SSD, on each and every a cold boot, Windows hangs on loading the **classpnp.sys** driver. It's only visible when booting into the safe mode, otherwise it just *freezes*. The strange thing here is the fact that restarting the machine solves the problem. In fact, I can start up the PC, instantly restart and everything is fine.

Now, I tried:

- deleting the **classpnp.sys** file and letting the recovery DVD restore the default driver file
- repairing the boot sector of the SSD
- changing the **Plug'n'Play OS** support option in BIOS
- changing the **ATA/IDE Configuration** (Disabled, Compatible and Enhanced) option in BIOS

... to no avail! What's rotten in the state of Denmark, I wonder?